# Can you boot an operating system into RAM disk and how?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, memory, ramdisk

I would like to know whether and how you can setup a computer to boot into RAM. I have 16GB of DDR3 1600MHz RAM.

Could it be done in Windows? If not, maybe in a light version of Unix?

You'd have to get a bit of background: I've built a high spec computer.
In Windows Index it is 7.5 + for all but the hard drive.

I have been experimenting with a RAM disk inside Windows running virtual machines with great success. I was woundering if you could boot a enviroment in a computer Directly in to a RAM disk as its primary hard drive.

From what I have seen is that there is an image of what's supposed to be on the RAM disks but the methods below haven't seamed seamless though.

As at boot I would like to take an image and put it into RAM, save it to an HD often so I don't get a corrupted system and can use it as a day to day computer.

A live CD that is dynamic.
I don't want an OS specific set to running in RAM like bartpe and Ubuntu.
I want a normal computer OS to be set in to RAM.

Comment: This seems to be a bit old, but: http://www.disklessangel.com/ ?

Comment: It appears that "yes, it's possible", see related info (off-site): [Windows 7 RC x86 in 4.75 GB RAM disk](http://reboot.pro/10234/).  Perhaps try some stuff out and come back with specific questions?

Comment: Thank you 
I was hoping for something free but I will give it ago

Comment: I believe UBCD4Win boots up with a ram disk. Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but it may be worth investigating: http://www.ubcd4win.com/

Comment: 16GB of disk space would be a bit light for Windows proper, so I wouldn't recommend trying.  (Windows PE, on the other hand, boots into a RAM disk by default.)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to give [KNOPPIX linux](http://www.knoppix.net/) a try:

> Knoppix is a Live Linux CD / Live DVD based on Debian GNU/Linux

Specially the [boot option *toram*](http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Live_CD_Tips#toram_cheat_code)

> At the boot prompt, type "knoppix toram". Knoppix will load the
>   contents of the CD into ram and run from there. After boot up, the CD
>   can be removed and the cd drive will be available for other uses.
>   Because this will take up a lot of ram, it is recommended for those
>   with at least 1 GB of ram.

Comment: yout to get a bit of back ground i built a nice computer on windows index it is 7 .5 + for all but the hard drive i have been expermenting with ramdisk inside wihdows running virtual macciens with great succses i was woundering if you could boot a enviroment in a computer that will use the ram disk as its primary hard drive
and from what i have seen is that thire is a img of whats suppost to be on the ramdisks but the metouds abouve havent seamed seamless

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to boot using RAM as storage space, but in theory it's possible. However, since RAM is volatile memory, unless you saved data to a persistent storage device (HDD, SSD, USB, CD, DVD, BD, Floppy disk, etc.), you would lose all the data on reboot. However, I suppose it's not physically impossible. It isn't possible for the BIOS/UEFI, as far as I know, to boot something into RAM directly, however, due to RAM being volatile memory, and thus incapable of storing an operating system after boot. However, it in theory ***could*** be possible to do something with ROM flash memory and/or boot sectors and/or boot-loaders to have something after UEFI/BIOS (for example, GNU GRUB), do something to run an OS in RAM. However, I have no idea how it'd be done, especially not on Windows.